# Bind color from

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn

My DataGrid holds the list of graphical objects (parabolas) with 3 numerical parameters and color (property named `br` of type `SolidColorBrush`).

I want to select color from ComboBox placed in `DataGridTemplateColumn` so that the selected value of type (`SolidColorBrush`) would be saved in the property called `br` of the selected item in DataGrid.

The picture shows how the main window is working:

[image: Main window working]

When new item is created, it is added to the DataGrid automatically, but `Color` column in DataGrid does not show its color. The ComboBox is also not updated when the `br` value is set programmatically in code.

When I choose the color value manually from the dropdown list it is not saved in `br` property of the selected item.

How do I properly organize data binding in this case?

My simple graphical elements class:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Reflection;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WpfParabola
{
    public class Parabola
    {
        public double a { get; set; } = 1;
        public double b { get; set; } = 1;
        public double c { get; set; } = 1;
        public SolidColorBrush br { get; set; } = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        PropertyInfo[] brushes = typeof(Brushes).GetProperties();

        public Parabola() { }
        public Parabola(Random rnd)
        {
            a = (double)rnd.Next(2, 20) / 100;
            b = (double)rnd.Next(2, 20) / 100;
            c = (double)rnd.Next(1, 30);
            int random = rnd.Next(brushes.Length);
            br = (SolidColorBrush)brushes[random].GetValue(null, null);
        }
        public Parabola(double _a, double _b, double _c)
        {
            a = _a;
            b = _b;
            c = _c;
        }
        public double y(double x)
        {
            return Math.Pow(a * x, 2) + b * x + c;
        }
    }
}
```

Main window code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfParabola.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfParabola"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="725"
    x:Name="_this">
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetType"
ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Type}" x:Key="colorsTypeOdp">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <sys:String>System.Windows.Media.Colors, PresentationCore,
        Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
        PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35</sys:String>
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
        <ObjectDataProvider ObjectInstance="{StaticResource colorsTypeOdp}"
MethodName="GetProperties" x:Key="colorPropertiesOdp">
        </ObjectDataProvider>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="300"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="0"
              Grid.Column="0"
              Name="parabolasDataGrid"
              CanUserAddRows="False"
              ItemsSource="{Binding parabolas}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="a" Width="20" Binding="{Binding a}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="b" Width="20" Binding="{Binding b}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="c" Width="20" Binding="{Binding c}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Color" Width="150">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource colorPropertiesOdp}}"
                                  SelectedItem ="{Binding br}">
                            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock Width="50" Height="{Binding ElementName=FontSize+4}" Margin="2" Background="{Binding Name}"/>
                                        <TextBlock  TextAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Canvas Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Name="parabolaCanvas"></Canvas>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <Button Padding="3" Margin="3" Click="Button_Click">Add parabola</Button>
        <Button Padding="3" Margin="3" IsCancel="True" Click="Button_Click_1">Close</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

and its code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfParabola
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        public ObservableCollection<Parabola> parabolas { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Parabola>();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            parabolasDataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        }
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Path path = new Path();
            PathGeometry geometry = new PathGeometry();
            PathFigure figure = new PathFigure();
            Parabola p = new Parabola(rnd);
            parabolas.Add(p);
            figure.StartPoint = new Point(1, p.y(1));
            for(double x=2; x<300; x += 0.5)
            {
                figure.Segments.Add(new LineSegment()
                {
                    Point = new Point(x, p.y(x))
                });
            }
            path.Stroke = p.br;
            path.StrokeThickness = 2;
            geometry.Figures.Add(figure);
            path.Data = geometry;
            parabolaCanvas.Children.Add(path);
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So you have a collection of parabolas that you are binding your collection to but you don't bind your SelectedItem on your ComboBox to your variable BR. You would also want to use NotifyPropertyChanged so you could update your grid when you select a different color.

Comment: I added `SelectedItem ="{Binding br}"`, is it correct? But the Property `br` in my `Parabola` class is not updating anyway. Maybe the issue is in type convertion. ComboBox is populated with `StaticResource colorPropertiesOdp` which is `PropertyInfo` collection, not brushes collection. How to deal with that?

Comment: that would be an issue, you can make your selected item whatever type colorPropertiesOdp is and when the property changes, update your br property. However, I would make an actual Type that has the properties you need rather than a propertyInfo collection and bind the comobBox to that.